# Functions, simple encryption beginner level

Tags: python

My assigment is to make a program with 2 functions. The first function is that the user inserts a word and the program prints out the same word but with `"*"` in between every letter e.g. `"*t*a*b*l*e*"`, this is working ok.

I need help with the second function, the program will print out the same word but the letters has moved one place, example `"ABCD"` will be "`BCDE"`. I have started by making an array with the alphabet but I don't know how to continue.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    print("*",s[i],sep='',end='')
    print("*")

def krypt():
    for i in(alfabet):
        print()

text = input("write a word ")
stars(text)
krypt()
print()
```

Comment: Walk us through your thought process. Why choose an array? What would you like the array to return for every index?

Comment: the functions `ord` and `chr` might come in handy, also probably the modulo operator `%` and possibly a `bytearray`. Or you hardcode everthing with a dictionary mapping and use `str.translate`.

Comment: If you have no questions regarding the first function, why mention it? Also, what should be the behaviour when you shift Z? Should it support both lower and upper case letters?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the encryption that you are trying is known as **Caesar Cipher**

You can try:

```
data = "ABCD"
shift = 1  
encypted_data_array = []
def krypt():
    for i in data:
        new = chr(ord(i) + shift)
        encypted_data_array.append(new)
print "".join(encypted_data_array)
```

Comment: Don't forget some kind of modulo operation, because a letter that is shifted past Z will give you unexpected results.

Comment: Yeah, after Z or z, we again can traverse to A / a by applying modulo operation.

Comment: Thank you, i get a invalid syntax error for line8, (print), Is data the word that the user inputs?

Comment: @djprofiler Please add () in print statement as you are working in python 3

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this if you have a list of char `alphabet` :

```
def krypt():
    print ([alfabet[-1]] + alfabet[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
import string


def krypt(str_to_encrypt, n=1):
    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
    d = {k: v for k, v in zip(alpha, alpha[n:] + alpha[:n])}
    out_s = ''.join(d.get(x.lower(), x) for x in str_to_encrypt)
    encrypted_str = ''.join(s.upper() if str.istitle(str_to_encrypt[i]) else s for i, s in enumerate(out_s))
    return encrypted_str


text = 'BCeD'
print(krypt(text))     # -> 'CDfE', default step is 1
print(krypt(text, 7))  # -> 'IJlK'
```

Printing out the dictionary `d` gives you an idea about the mechanics behind it:

```
>> d
{'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd', ... 'y': 'z', 'z': 'a'}
```

---

- Case-preserving
- Handles non-alphabet characters (leaves them intact).

Comment: If the dictionary contains both the lower and upper case letters, you will only need one pass over the string. And by generalising the shift with a parameter, you get a Caesar cipher.

Answer (score 0):

You want the letter with the index increased by 1 or decreased by 25 for each letter, so if 'a' is index 0 'b' will be index 1 or index -25 (in english alphabet).
starting from the tail of the list does not generate index out of range.

with this theory, you can write:

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
def kcrypt(word):
    return ''.join(alphabet[alphabet.index(l)-len(alphabet)+1] for l in word)

print kcrypt(word)
```

Comment: Thank you, i want the letter increased by 1.

Comment: if you have 26 letters, +1 and -25 are index for the same letter. string.ascii_lowercase[x+1] == string.ascii_lowercase[x-25] is true